# Gift PS4 to remote family with access to PSN content

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I'm going to ship my old PS4 to my brother as a gift and would like to leave him with access to the digital games I own and PS+ Premium.  Ideally, I'd be able to make him and my nephew and accounts under mine so they have access to all that, but he is able to buy new games if he wants, while I continue using my account as normal on my PS5.  Is that possible?

Are there any other considerations or steps I'd need to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set that PS4 as your main console, then your brother/nephew just create their accounts on that console and your digital games should be available for everyone. In this way they can have their own PSN account and buy new games from the PSN store without affecting yours.

This, however, forces you to have an active Internet connection whenever you login on another PS4 in order to use your games.